# Given reals $x, y , z \ne 0$ satisfying $x^2 - xy + yz$ $= y^2 - yz + zx = z^2 - zx + xy$, calculate the value of $\dfrac{(x + y + z)^3}{xyz}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Given reals $x, y , z \ne 0$ satisfying $$\large x^2 - xy + yz = y^2 - yz + zx = z^2 - zx + xy$$, calculate the value of $\dfrac{(x + y + z)^3}{xyz}$.

This is what I oftentimes do when I am unproductive.

Sure, the obvious answeris $\dfrac{(x + y + z)^3}{xyz} = 27$, occuring when $x = y = z$. But there's another answer, which is $\dfrac{(x + y + z)^3}{xyz} = 49$, which occurs when, well, I don't know, it's written in the solution I have provided, check it out!

Comment: In my approach which is different from yours, I've just got that $\frac{(x+y+z)^3}{xyz}=49$ when $(x,y,z)=(ak,k,\frac{a^2-a-1}{a-2}k)$ where $k$ is a non-zero real number and $a$ is a real number such that $a^3 - 5 a^2 + 6 a - 1=0$. WolframAlpha says $a\approx 0.19806, 1.5550, 3.2470$. I hope this comment helps since you wrote "..., which occurs when, well, I don't know".

Comment: Thanks for that. I was kind of worried that there wouldn't exist $x, y, z$ that satisfies the condition I put out at the end of my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity, let $\left\{ \begin{align} a &= x^2 - xy + yz\\ b &= y^2 - yz + zx\\ c &= z^2 - zx + xy \end{align} \right.$ and $a = b = c = k$, we have that $$ab + bc + ca = \frac{(a + b + c)^2 - (a^2 + b^2 + c^2)}{2}$$

$$ = \frac{\displaystyle \left[\sum_{cyc}(x^2 - xy + yz)\right]^2 - \sum_{cyc}(x^2 - xy + yz)^2}{2}$$

$$ = \frac{\displaystyle (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2 - \sum_{cyc}[x^4 + (xy)^2 + (yz)^2 - 2(x^3y - y^2zx + x^2yz)]}{2}$$

$$ = x^3y + y^3z + z^3x$$

Since $a = b = c \iff (a + b + c)^2 = 3(ab + bc + ca)$, $(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2 = 3(x^3y + y^3z + z^3x)$

Let $u = x + y + z, v = xy + yz + zx, w = xyz$, we obtain that $u^2 - 2v = 3k$ $(1)$.

Furthermore, it could be observed that $$9k^2 - 2v^2 + 5wu = u^4 - 4u^2v + 2v^2 + 5wu$$

$$ = (x^4 + y^4 + z^4) + xyz(x + y + z) = \sum_{cyc}[x^2(x^2 - xy + yz)] + (x^3y + y^3z + z^3x)$$

$$ = (x^2a + y^2b + z^2c) + 3k^2 = (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)k + 3k^2 = 6k^2 \implies 2v^2 - 5wu = 3k^2 \ (2)$$

Moreover, it could be perceived that $$v^2 - 2wu = (xy)^2 + (yz)^2 + (zx)^2$$

$$ = \sum_{cyc}[xy(x^2 - xy + zx)] = xya + yzb + zxc = (xy + yz + zx)k = vk \ (3)$$

From equations $(2)$ and $(3)$, we have that $$5(v^2 - 2wu) - 2(2v^2 - 5wu) = 5vk - 2 \cdot 3k^2 \iff v^2 - 5vk + 6k^2 = 0$$

which leads to whether $v = 2k$ or $v = 3k$.

If $v = 2k$ then $wu = k^2$ and from equation $(1)$, we have that $u^2 = 2v + 3k = 7k$

$\implies \dfrac{(x + y + z)^3}{xyz} = \dfrac{u^3}{w} = \dfrac{(u^2)^2}{wu} = \dfrac{(7k)^2}{k^2} = 49$.

If $v = 3k$ then $wu = 3k^2$ and from equation $(1)$, we have that $u^2 = 2v + 3k = 9k$

$\implies \dfrac{(x + y + z)^3}{xyz} = \dfrac{u^3}{w} = \dfrac{(u^2)^2}{wu} = \dfrac{(9k)^2}{3k^2} = 27$.